# Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Credentials?

Tags: angular

What does it mean?

I have import:

```
import {Credentials} from '../_models/credentials/credentials.model';
```

And constructor:

```
constructor(private router: Router,
private credential: Credentials){
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant inject a model class in the constructor. It needs to be `@Injectable()` and set as a provider  to be used by Angular's DI.

Change your constructor to:

```
constructor(private router: Router)
```

Comment: Are you right? `constructor(private router: Router)`?

Comment: Can you share all smple?

Comment: If Credentials is not a provider then it cant be  set as constructor parameter and injected. That is what the error means..  From the code you have posted, it is a model class and not a provider

Comment: But this class has `export class Credentials {}`

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#angular-dependency-injection

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject a model in the constructor. Define `credential` as a class variable.

```
import {Credentials} from '../_models/credentials/credentials.model';
// ... 
//
private credential: Credentials;
// ... ...
//
constructor(private router: Router){ }
```

Comment: It worsk for all injection. Also when I try inject service: `public timer: TimerService`

Comment: because TimerService is an @Injectable service. Your Credentials model is not injectable.